# How to remove leading 0 from c# datagridview?

Tags: c#

I have a c# datagridview populated using a csv file.It works fine.I have a column with some account numbers as below.

[image]

I want to remove leading 0 of this column.Tried below code but not working.Is that because data source was csv file? how can I remove the "0" from this column?

```
private void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "AccountNumber")
        {
            if (e.Value != null)
            {

                this.dataGridView.Columns["AccountNumber"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c"; 

            }
            else
            {
                           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `int.Parse()` the string or `TrimStart('0')`

Comment: can you post the piece of code where you populate your `dataGridView`? I guess the easiest way would be to convert it to a `long`. I guess the "AccountNumber" is of type string?

Comment: You really __need__ to decide/know whether you want numbers or strings in the cells!! @fubo shows the solution for both, but the results are so fundamentally different so should think about what you want!